# Public Message Queue Exception : Message Queue Exception : Queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation

Tags: c#, active-directory, msmq

we are developing an application which is running on AD Network and it uses MSMQ public MQ to communicate over network.

We created a user group and we gave "full control" permission to that group on Message Queuing but the application throw the following exception

> Message Queue Exception : Queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation

we gave "full control" permission to "everyone" user on Message Queuing than the application runs well.

Because of the security issues we cannot gave "full control" permission to "everyone" user.
Therefore, is there any one that knows how can we gave permission to a group on Message Queuing ?

Comment: Never done this but here is a suggestion.  I think when you send a message there is an option to include who the sender is.  If you do not send who you are and the queue has access controls, it will always reject those messages.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Brain, after his comment, I checked the security options on MSMQ,
then I recognize that even if the users has permission to access, the computer accounts has not!
When I gave access permission to computer accounts, application run well.